# Biztalk 2010 aggregation

Tags: csv, biztalk, aggregation

I got an input xml file like this :

```
<root>
   <item ...>
   <item ...>
   <item ...>
</root>
```

and I need to construct and send messages in 2 ways in the same orchestration :
1. Send to one destination as 1 xml file per item
2. Send the whole bunch of "item" as one single csv flat file.

My file is actually handled by a pipeline that extracts every "item" from the envelope.  The problem is that I need to merge all "items" based on a certain condition.

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Comment: I forgot to tell... the bunch of items to be sent should be filtred by a condition.  It is not all of the items that are going to be sent in the csv flat file.

Comment: why in the same orchestration? Biztalk is publish/subscribe. One orchestration subscribes to this already debatched <item> and processes it. Another orchestration has a correlation set based on the filter condition and aggregates all the <item>'s and finally sends the .csv out.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be at least 2 ways of going about this - it isn't clear as to how you 'arrive' at the input xml file batch - this will drive the decision, IMO.

1. Since it seems that you've already got all the messages in a single xml batch at the start, this should be quite easy. Before you debatch them in a pipeline, you need to ensure that you also publish this batch message (`root` ...) into the messagebox if it isn't already so (i.e. Direct binding, if the message doesn't already come from the messagebox).

   You can then create a map for the CSV file which takes the root message as input and then filters out the `item`s which you don't want in the CSV. To do the filtering in the Map, you could use a looping [functoid with conditionals](http://geekswithblogs.net/benny/archive/2006/02/04/68178.aspx), or my preference would just to be to implement the map in xslt and then apply templates just to desirable `item`s with an xpath filter. A subscribing FILE send port, which filters (BTS.MessageType) to the incoming xml batch message can then apply this map.

   The individual xml files would then be processed by your debatching pipeline and then another subscribing Physical FILE send port can write them out.

   2 . Alternatively, if it is too late and the `root` xml file has been debatched (and you can't get to the original Xml file FWR), you would need to use another orch to reassemble the messages needed for the CSV (scatter and gather). This will be more complicated, as you will likely need to correlate the messages (e.g. on some batch identifier), or apply a timer, etc.

   Have a look at the [Pipeline Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561747.aspx) sample on how to collect the 'desirable' CSV messages into a `Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.SendPipelineInputMessages` variable using a loop, and then use a pipeline to assemble the batch. If the criteria for 'desirable' are already promoted on the individual item messages, then you can apply the filter on your receive, but if not, you will need to use a decision in your loop to determine whether or not to add the message to the batch.

Comment: actually, the xml is a result from an SQL extraction save as a xmlfile.  The file is actually processsed as the 'root' item is the enveloppe and every item is a separate message.  I did this with a pipeline.  The problem is that in the same orch I need to save individual items as xml files and also some of them as a single csv file.